# Why do `tf.pad` padding arguments need additional incrementation for accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, caffe

I'm trying to implement a symmetric padding layer in Keras, which is just like how Caffe implements it and I've encountered a weird problem.

Let's say we have an `1x1280x1280x3` image with `3` channels, and we want to perform a convolution to it so that it returns an object of a shape `1x320x320x96` with `96` channels. In Caffe, we can set `pad` parameter right in the convolution layer:

```
input: "image"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
  dim: 1280
  dim: 1280
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "image"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    pad: 5  # Padding parameter
    stride: 4
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
```

If you try to compile this with Caffe, output shape of `conv1` will indeed be `1x320x320x96`.

---

Now let's try the same thing with Keras using `tf.pad` and `Lambda` layer:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
import tensorflow as tf

image = Input(shape=(1280, 1280, 3),
                   dtype='float32',
                   name='image')
sym_pad = Lambda(lamda x: tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [0, 5], [0, 5], [0, 0]]))  # padding = 5
conv1 = Conv2D(filters=96,
               kernel_size=11,
               strides=(4, 4),
               activation=relu,
               padding='valid',  # valid instead of 'same'
               name='conv1')(image)
```

**Problem**:

If we measure the shape of `conv1` defined from the code above, it will be `1x319x319x96` instead of`1x320x320x96`.

But if we increment our padding with `2`, therefore utilize a `7x7` pad instead of `5x5`, like this:

```
sym_pad = Lambda(lamda x: tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [0, 5+2], [0, 5+2], [0, 0]]))  # padding = 7
```

`conv1` will have a desired shape of `1x320x320x96` when we pass a padded input of `image` with a shape of `1x1287x1287x3` instead of `1x1285x1285x3` (**notice** that only odd padding on the even-shaped image alters the shape of convolution, this might be related to strides).

Why is this happening? Does Caffe automatically increment every padding parameter by `2`? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

P.S
I am aware of `padding=same` parameter in Keras layers, but I'm looking for symmetric padding instead of asymmetric one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about symmetric padding, I assume that you want to pad the same amount of pixel to the left side of the image as well as to the right side (same for top and bottom). What you are doing currently with `tf.pad` is padding 5 pixels to the right and 5 pixels to the bottom. Therefore you are padding 2.5 pixel to both sides (in theory).

The output shape is given by:

```
floor((input_size-kernel_size+2*padding_size)/stride_size) + 1
```

So in your case when padding 2.5 pixels this yields and output shape of 319.
If you would pad 5 pixels to both sides you would obtain, what you would expect i.e. 320.

Comment: I apologize if I'm misunderstanding anything. But let's say we have an image of shape `(1, 1280, 1280, 3)`, my code would return a shape `(1, 1285, 1285, 3)`, so that it symmetrically pads height and width dimensions of image. Float values can't be passed to `tf.pad`.

Comment: But I've noticed, that array shapes are used for that purpose exactly. So I should use `[[0, 0], [5, 5], [5, 5], [0, 0]]` as a padding parameter instead, to evenly pad from all sides! I didn't know the purpose of this before... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your example you pad the input only to the bottom and to the right. Use:

```
sym_pad = Lambda(lamda x: tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [5, 5], [5, 5], [0, 0]]))
```

to get the same padding like in Caffe.

Comment: I was unaware of that due to slightly complex documentation of `tf.pad` on tensorflow. But now it returns a desired output. Thank you!